# Configuring Syslog to accept remote log submissions

Tags: logging, daemon, syslog

By default syslog daemons don't accept remote log submissions. I need mine to, but don't really have a clue how to configure that. Can anyone help me out, send me a good tutorial, etc. I have been googling for awhile, but can seem to find what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Read the man-page for your operating system (`man syslogd`). [On FreeBSD](http://www.manpages.info/freebsd/syslogd.8.html), you need to pass `-a` and the addresses of white-listed senders to the syslogd invocation.

Answer (score 0):

man syslogd
     -r     This option will enable the facility to receive message from the
              network using an internet domain socket with the syslog  service
              (see  services(5)).   The default is to not receive any messages
              from the network.

on centos, should be like this
$  cat /etc/sysconfig/syslog |grep OPT
SYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-m 0 -r"